# iOS Safari - pages opened to new tab inherit history, is this behavior documented?

Tags: javascript, webkit

Repro steps:

- Open a page #1 on iOS Safari
- Open a link from it into a new or background tab (#2)
- Do (via safari dev tools) `history.length` - it will show a history of tab #1. Also, `history.go(-1)` will go to a page #1 in a tab #2

This is probably happening because iOS is trying to keep a smooth experience for the user (if a page opens a link into a new tab, you can still navigate back via UI button, and this will close the new tab and return to the previous tab).

I want to ask:

1. Is this behavior (specific to *mobile* safari) documented somewhere?
2. Is it possible to distinguish a link opened into a new tab (in other browsers, such a link has `history.length == 1`, but not here)? It would be helpful if I want to help user get back, as I'd need to do `window.close()` (= close tab #2) instead of `history.go(-1)` (= opens page #1 in tab #2).

Thanks!